# The Effect of Input and Feedback Capacitors on an Operational Amplifier Open-Loop Gain Response

Tags: operational-amplifier, stability, loop-gain, phase-margin

I have the following circuit that I want to compensate:

[image: Circuit step response without compensation]

As shown from the step response, the circuit is unstable because of the high input capacitance (the green plot is without any additional input capacitance, while the blue plot is with the 520 pF input capacitance connected). I plotted the open-loop gain AC response to calculate the phase margin:

[image: Open-loop gain bode plot without compensation]

As can be seen from the plot above, the phase margin is around 0 degrees. Comparing between the blue and green plot also shows the additional pole caused by the 520 pF input capacitance at around 600 kHz (This cutoff frequency is exactly as calculated with the equation shown after the following paragraph). As a note, to acquire the open-loop gain AC response with LTSpice, I used the method shown in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YYWlPFBebfc&t=293s).

As explained in [an article by Texas Instruments on Op amp stability and input capacitance](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slyt087/slyt087.pdf), adding a feedback capacitor can create an open-loop zero that can compensate for the input capacitance pole. The equation describing the open-loop gain AC response with both input and feedback capacitor is rewritten below:

$$ A\beta = \frac{a R_{G}}{R_{F}+R_{G}}\frac{1+sR_{G}C_{in}}{1+s(R_{F}||R_{G})C_{F}}$$

Inserting the following values to the above equation,

$$C_{in} = 520 pF, R_{G} = 1 k\Omega, R_{F} = 1 k\Omega, C_{F} = 520 pF, $$

yield the pole and zero to completely cancel each other:

$$ A\beta = 0.5a\frac{1+\frac{s}{2\pi(306k)}}{1+\frac{s}{2\pi(306k)}}$$

When I plot the open-loop gain AC response with the component values listed above:

[image: Open-loop gain bode plot wit compensation]

The pole at 300 kHz (originally at 600 kHz) really is gone, keeping the slope at -20 dB/decade at around that frequency. However, there seems to be another pole introduced at around 50 MHz, causing the phase margin to drop to around 0 degrees again and decreasing the slope at high frequencies from -40 dB/decade to -60 dB/decade.

So my question is: **Where does this additional pole come from? Why is it that it doesn't show in the equation above?**

P.S: Yes, I can find a value for the feedback capacitor that improves the phase margin of the original circuit by sweeping the feedback capacitor value, therefore I don't have any knowledge of why it works, which I want to find out.

Comment: I'm not sure I'd make both stray input C and the compensating C exactly the same parameter {cin}, are you sweeping both, or fixing cin and sweeping ccomp?

Comment: What's the point of using this opamp without a feedback, i.e. open loop? Not sure if this opamp is stable at all, without a feedback.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič Hi, I will not use it in an open-loop configuration. FB- is internally connected to OUT- while FB+ is internally connected to OUT+. And as you can see in the first figure, IN-/IN+ is connected to FB-/FB+ through a feedback resistor. Sorry if it wasn't clear, I'll add the information on FB+/FB- to the question :). However, to get the value of the phase margin, of course, I still have to analyze it in an open-loop configuration (While still maintaining the correct closed loop biasing). The video I linked in the question explains this concept better.

Comment: @Neil_UK Hi, for the first question, yup, it is not the same parameter. However, because it turns out the value of CF to compensate Cin is exactly equal to Cin in this case, I made it equal. So basically I plotted the case with an additional input capacitance (Cin = 520 pF) with its compensating capacitor (which in this case is also 520 pF to fully compensate the pole) AND the case without any additional capacitance nor compensation (Cin = 0, CF = 0) just as a reference. For the second question, I fixed Cin while sweeping CF, the value of capacitance to compensate for the existence of Cin.